# c# Leaner way of initializing int array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, initialization

Having the following code is there a leaner way of initializing the array from 1 to the number especified by a variable?

```
int nums=5;
int[] array= new int[nums];

for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
{
   array[i] = i;
}
```

Maybe with linq or some array.function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int[] array = Enumerable.Range(0, nums).ToArray();
```

Comment: This might create an array which allocates too much memory. `ToArray` does not know how many elements are in `Enumerable.Range`. Hence it needs to foreach all of them and always increase the capacity(using a doubling algorith). So you might end with an array which consumes nearly twice as much memory as necessary. –

Comment: @TimSchmelter Is there then some alternative as simple as this but with less resource consumption? (in my case the range would go to 30 at max...)

Comment: @ase69s If only 30 entries, then don't worry about it. EDIT: Otherwise, all I can think of is pre-initializing something like a `List` to your capacity: `var items = new List<int>(nums);items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, nums));`

Comment: Here's a question related to this issue: [High memory consumption with Enumerable.Range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519275/high-memory-consumption-with-enumerable-range) @ase69s: You don't need to care if you only have 30 items.

Comment: thank you all for your detailed explanations ^^, answer accepted then

Comment: And here duplicate question that contians a lot of ways to improve initialization of a large array - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980570/how-to-intialize-integer-array-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Enumerable.Range()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) method instead of. Don't forget to add [`System.Linq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.aspx) namespace. But this could spend little bit high memory. You can use like;

```
int[] array = Enumerable.Range(0, nums).ToArray();
```

> Generates a sequence of integral numbers within a specified range.

Comment: Also, `ToArray` does not know how many elements are in `Enumerable.Range`. Hence it needs to `foreach` all of them always increasing the capacity(using a doubling algorith). So you might end with an array which consumes nearly twice as much memory as necessary.  Here's my own question regarding this issue: [High memory consumption with Enumerable.Range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519275/high-memory-consumption-with-enumerable-range)

Answer (score 0):

Using [Enumerable.Range](http://www.dotnetperls.com/enumerable-range)

```
int[] array = Enumerable.Range(0, nums).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but here is the best way I know of:

`int[] data = new int [] { 383, 484, 392, 975, 321 };`

from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays)

even simpler:

`int[] data = { 383, 484, 392, 975, 321 };`