# Initialize an integer array with a single value in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I quicky fill an array with a specific value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089076/how-do-i-quicky-fill-an-array-with-a-specific-value)

Is there a way to initialize an integer array with a single value like -1 without having to explicitly assign each item?

Basically, if I have

```
int[] MyIntArray = new int[SomeCount];
```

All items are assigned 0 by default. Is there a way to change that value to -1 without using a loop? or assigning explicitly each item using {}?

Comment: Also check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980570/how-to-intialize-integer-array-in-c-sharp/ which discusses how to do it efficiently and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519275/high-memory-consumption-with-enumerable-range how not to use ToArray for large arrays.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
int[] myIntArray = Enumerable.Repeat(-1, 20).ToArray();
```

Comment: Don't forget the `.ToArray()`

Comment: +1 for all ToArray once. Before using please read [High memory consumption with Enumerable.Range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519275/high-memory-consumption-with-enumerable-range) if your array is large.

Comment: And for types other than int, use the template form, eg. Enumerable.Repeat<UInt32>(1,20).ToArray();

Comment: @dlchambers or `Enumerable.Repeat(1U, 20).ToArray();`

Answer (score 18):

You could use the [Enumerable.Repeat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899.aspx) method

```
int[] myIntArray = Enumerable.Repeat(1234, 1000).ToArray()
```

will create an array of 1000 elements, that all have the value of 1234.

Comment: Only answer that is clear.

Answer (score 14):

If you've got a single value (or just a few) you can set them explicitly using a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062%28v=VS.110%29.aspx)

```
int[] MyIntArray = new int[] { -1 };
```

If you've got lots, you can use [Enumerable.Repeat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) like this

```
int[] MyIntArray = Enumerable.Repeat(-1, YourArraySize).ToArray();
```

Comment: put some size in new int[Size] and this statement will not work. Even if you put a static size like 50. 

So, I don't think that this is right answer.

Comment: @FarhanHafeez You're absolutely correct, I originally misread the question and immediately went to edit my answer, my apologies

Comment: Only answer to address the "without using a loop"