# fill an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

In Java there are about 18 a static "fill" methods in the class Arrays that serve to assign one value to each element in an array. I'm looking for an equivalent in C# to achieve the same thing but I'm not finding anything with the same compactness:

1) ForEach as I understand passes elements in the array by value so I can't change them

2) Repeat from Enumerable creates a new array, it seems to be overhead to create a new array and then copy each element from the array

3) a for-loop isn't pretty, which I guess is why the Java folks introduced this compact notation to begin with

4) The Clear method from the Array class can set everything to zero, but then how do I convert zero to the non-zero value I want?

To demonstrate Java's syntax consider this code that prints three times the number 7:

```
int[] iii = {1, 2, 3};
Arrays.fill(iii, 7);
for (int i : iii) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: post a Java example, maybe then I understand what you want

Comment: Dont know java's 18 methods. post a example.

Comment: why complicate when there isnt any need to complicate..

Comment: this can help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210369/initialize-an-integer-array-with-a-single-value-in-c-sharp-net?rq=1]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Write yourself an extension method

```
public static class ArrayExtensions {
    public static void Fill<T>(this T[] originalArray, T with) {
        for(int i = 0; i < originalArray.Length; i++){
            originalArray[i] = with;
        }
    }  
}
```

and use it like

```
int foo[] = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0};
foo.Fill(13);
```

will fill all the elements with 13

Answer (score 67):

```
int[] arr = Enumerable.Repeat(42, 10000).ToArray();
```

I believe that this does the job :)

Comment: I was aware of this method as I mentioned in the OP, I was looking for something that modified an existing array.

Answer (score 13):

You could try something like this:

I have initialzed the array for having value 5, you could put your number similarly.

```
int[] arr = new int[10]; // your initial array

arr = arr.Select(i => 5).ToArray(); // array initialized to 5.
```

Comment: It **creates** new array, not **fills** existing one.

Answer (score 5):

Say you want to fill with number 13.

`int[] myarr = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(n => 13).ToArray();`

or

`List<int> myarr = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(n => 13).ToList();`

if you prefer a list.

Comment: isn't this creating a new array? Arrays.fill() is not doing that in Java, it is modifying an existing one.

Comment: Since the question was about filling an array with a constant value (i.e. just for initialization), I assumed that you were creating the array right there and then. So I tried to provide a short answer. If your array already existed before, I'd use the Select method in Igoy's answer.

Comment: I like this answer since it gives me the opportunity to choose the index range in which the constant will be injected. +1!

Comment: When using EF, I love the list idea, as it is easy to work with and already in common usage for many other entities and objects. +1 here

Answer (score 4):

you could write an extension method

```
public static void Fill<T>(this T[] array, T value)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) 
  {
     array[i] = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Copy pasting a previous answer is not so cool ;-)

Comment: I did not copy paste anyone's answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void Fill<T>(this IList<T> col, T value, int fromIndex, int toIndex)
{
    if (fromIndex > toIndex)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("fromIndex");

    for (var i = fromIndex; i <= toIndex; i++)
        col[i] = value;
}
```

Something that works for all `IList<T>`s.

Comment: `IList<T>` is still `T[]`

Comment: If such a generic function - I'd use default prms... public static void Fill<T>(this IList<T> col, T value, int fromIndex=0, int toIndex=-1)
        {
            if (toIndex == -1)
                toIndex = col.Count-1;