# How do I split a line of text and assign the result to a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to read a text file full of medical records delimited by a pipe.  There are about 20 columns of data and millions of rows. The size of the text file is around 1GB.

The first step is reading the data. Here's my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strFilePath = @"abcrecords.txt";
        string[,] myArray;

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(strFilePath, FileMode.Open))
        using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            while (!rdr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] strFileLine = rdr.ReadLine().Split('|');
                {
                    myArray = strFileLine;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I get the results of the split line (which has 20 elements) into the first row of `myArray`. Then add each new split line to `myArray`? Right now, I get the error:

> Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string[*,*]'

Comment: Why are you declaring a two dimensional array for `myArray`?

Comment: @Oded I thought that the final array is 2-dimensional ie. 20 columns and X number of millions of rows?  Perhaps I am going about this all wrong?

Comment: Like SLaks said, you want a List<string[]>. You don't know how many lines the file has in advance, so it doesn't make sense to declare an array to hold the records.

Comment: @phan - OK, but you are trying to assign a _single_ dimension array to your _two_ dimensional array in `myArray = strlFileLine;`.

Comment: There are so many issues with this code... (1) use a single `using` statement, you only have one resource; (2) use `List<>`, not array, (3) put some error handling or your app will crash if the file doesn't exist; (4) read the string in the while and check if it's not null instead of EndOfStream redundant call

Comment: @phan The result of `Split` is going to be a 1 dimensional array with 2 entries `strFileLine[0]` being the string before `|` and `strFileLine[1]` being the string after `|`.

Comment: @vane - Um. No. If there are multiple `|` in the string, you will get that number + 1 entries in the array.

Comment: @Oded you're correct, I was over simplifying and breaking it down to a smaller case. I was trying to illustrate the functionality of split so OP understands it returns a 1 dimensional array and not a 2 dimensional one.

Comment: An other issue being loading the entire thing in to memory at once. I know we've gone past the days of a 640K limit but this sort of thing still sets my teeth on edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        File.ReadAllLines("abcrecords.txt").Select(x => x.Split('|')).ToArray();
```

**Update**

Because file is large you can use:

```
        var result = new List<string[]>();
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(strFilePath, FileMode.Open))
        using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            while (!rdr.EndOfStream)
            {
                result.Add(rdr.ReadLine().Split('|')))
            }
        }
```

But it will be very expensive to store such big object in memory.

Comment: Same problem as above.  The text file is 1GB large, so I run into memory problems.  See my comment to Tim Schmelter.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `List<string[]>` instead if you want to modify it, an array is immutable. You can also use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) which is more comfortable as the `StreamReader` (imho):

```
List<string[]> allLines = File.ReadLines(path)
    .Select(l => l.Split('|').ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

Note that above is a Linq query which requires to add `using System.Linq`.

A final note about memory consumption of my approach. `File.ReadLines` uses a `StreamReader` under the hood which reads one line at a time unlike `File.ReadAllLines` which reads all into memory at once, but you can also improve this approach even more:

Have a look at my own question which is related: [High memory consumption with Enumerable.Range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519275/high-memory-consumption-with-enumerable-range)

So you can first read the number of lines to initialize the list with the correct size:

```
int count = File.ReadLines(path).Count();
var allLines = new List<string[]>(count);
var lines = File.ReadLines(path).Select(l => l.Split('|').ToArray());
allLines.AddRange(lines);
```

Otherwise you could end with a list that needs nearly 100% more memory than required due to the doubling size algorith from `List.Add`.

But you should really consider to use a database instead.

Comment: Since there are millions of rows I was told that it's best to use StreamReader.  While your code compiles and runs I get the error 'System.OutofMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll, for your line of code.

Comment: Well if that's an issue your code will struggle badly reading it in to an array as well. This way all the data is in memory twice (ish for a bit), once as teh file, and once as List of arrays. Do you have enough memory lying about to afford to have it all in memory once, do you need it all at once.

Comment: +1 @TonyHopkinson. Exactly. Why do you need to have millions of records in memory at the *same* time? What are you doing with them ultimately?

Comment: I don't need it all at once.  Ultimately, I want to analyze the data and do things like calculate the average age of patients living in a particular zipcode.  Also, do things like count, min, max, median, etc.

Comment: Me thinks you need to close this question and have a think then. What were you planning on doing with it when you'd read it in, outputting to another file, sending it to some service, storing in a db, displaying a page full??

Comment: "Ultimately, I want to analyze the data and do things like calculate the average age of patients living in a particular zipcode. Also, do things like count, min, max, median, etc" Then you should put into a database and then run queries against the data.

Comment: @phan: `File.ReadLines` uses a `StreamReader` internally which reads one line at a time unlike `File.ReadAllLines` which reads all into memory at once.

Comment: @aquinas. Point taken.  I know nothing about databases.  Given that I'd like to use C# as much as possible can you point me in the direction of which database I should consider learning to use.

Comment: @Tim Thank you Tim for helping me understand the difference.

Comment: @phan, grab a free copy of SQL Server Express.

Comment: @Tim I read your edited answer, thanks again for helping me out.  I am taking yours and aquinas' suggestions and will learn to use SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowed the start of Alexander Balte.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("", FileMode.Open))
{
  using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fs))
  {
    while (!rdr.EndOfStream)
    {
      DoSomethingWith(rdr.ReadLine().Split('|')));
    }
  }
}
void DoSomethingWith(String[] argColumns)
{
  // on y va
}
```