# Get certain item from each Tuple from List

Tags: c#, string, list, tuples

What is the correct way to go about creating a list of, say, the first item of each `Tuple` in a `List` of `Tuples`?

If I have a `List<Tuple<string,string>>`, how would I get a `List<string>` of the first string in each `Tuple`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A little Linq will do the trick:

```
var myStringList = myTupleList.Select(t=>t.Item1).ToList();
```

As an explanation, since Tim posted pretty much the same answer, Select() creates a 1:1 "projection"; it takes each input element of the Enumerable, and for each of them it evaluates the lambda expression and returns the result as an element of a new Enumerable having the same number of elements. ToList() will then spin through the Enumerable produced by Select(), and add each element one at a time to a new `List<T>` instance.

Tim has a good point on the memory-efficiency; ToList() will create a list and add the elements one at a time, which will cause the List to keep resizing its underlying array, doubling it each time to ensure it has the proper capacity. For a big list, that could cause OutOfMemoryExceptions, and it will cause the CLR to allocate more memory than necessary to the List unless the number of elements happens to be a power of 2.

Answer (score 6):

```
List<string> list = tuples.Select(t => t.Item1).ToList();
```

or, potentially less memory expensive:

```
List<string> list = new List<String>(tuples.Count);
list.AddRange(tuples.Select(t => t.Item1));
```

because it avoids  the doubling algorithm of `List.Add` in `ToList`.

Comment: I would consider the second suggestion a microoptimization in most cases and avoid it - it just adds noise to the code.

Comment: @DanielBrückner: Yes, mentioned it just because people are sometimes too generous with `ToList` or `ToArray`. When the seqeunce is large you can avoid `OutOfMemoryExceptions` with the second approach. It can safe up to 50% memory. Will never forget it myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519275/high-memory-consumption-with-enumerable-range

Comment: A more concise way is to pass in the IEnumerable to the list constructor. The List will size itself to exactly the needed capacity, and this becomes a one-liner.

Comment: @KeithS: No, that works only if the `IEnumerable` can be casted to `ICollection` what is not the case above. Therefore `ToList` enumerates the whole sequence using `List.Add`(with or without the constructor).

Comment: A look at TypeDescriptor backs you up. My mistake (or rather, MSDN's mistake, since it does assert that the List will be appropriately sized).

Comment: @KeithS: No, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx) just tells that the list will have    _"**sufficient capacity** to accommodate the number of elements copied"_. So the size is always sufficient to hold all copied elements, but it can be too  large(nearly 100% more than needed).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `List<Tuple<string, string>> listoftuples`, you can use the List's implementation of the Select method to take the first string from each Tuple.

It would look like this:

```
List<string> firstelements = listoftuples.Select(t => t.Item1).ToList();
```

Comment: It's not a method of `List<T>`; it's part of the System.Linq library.

Comment: Right, but List has an implementation of it. I've clarified my answer a bit.

Comment: `Select` is an extension method defined in `Enumerable<T>` and will work with everything implementing `IEnumerable<T>` - `List<T>` is nothing special in this context.

Comment: @Jim - It does not. Check the MSDN docs. It's an extension method, which can be applied to a List because Lists are ILists which are IEnumerables. However, it's defined by the static System.Linq.Enumerable class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know that. My point was just that the Select method can be used - since that's (better-)covered in other answers, I'll probably just delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

Generialised Variant:
for selecting a particular item where the collection's tuple's length is unknown i.e 2,3,4 ...:

```
    static IEnumerable TupleListSelectQuery<T>(IEnumerable<T> lst, int index) where T : IStructuralEquatable, IStructuralComparable, IComparable
    {
        return lst.Select(t => typeof(T).GetProperty("Item" + Convert.ToString(itemNumber)).GetValue(t)).ToList();
    }
```

where *index*'s value corresponds to the way tuples are enumerated i.e 1,2,3 ... (not 0,1,2...).