# C# extracting ID from list of structures using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of structures:

```
struct MyStruct{
    int ID;
    string name;
    string surname;
}
List<MyStruct> list1 = new List<MyStruct>();
///here the list is being updated so that it has some elements
```

Now I want to extract from **list1** all **ID**'s and put into another list:

```
List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
list2.AddRange(list1.GetIds() /*LINQ HERE*/);
```

The trick is I would like to use LINQ to do it but I still don't understand it quite well. I know it can be done with ordinary *for loop* but **I want to use AddRange and LINQ**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that  `GetIds` doesn't exist and you want to do it with LINQ instead. The method you need is [`Enumerable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
list2.AddRange(list1.Select(x => x.ID));
```

You could also use `ToList` instead of `AddRange`:

```
List<int> list2 = list1.Select(x => x.ID).ToList();
```

Micro/Premature-optimization hint: `AddRange` and `ToList` don't know the size of the input sequence if it is not a collection. Therefore they enumerate the sequence and use `List.Add` to add the items. This causes resizes of the backing array. It can also lead to a [higher memory consumption than necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519275/high-memory-consumption-with-enumerable-range).

You could circumvent it with:

```
List<int> list2 = new List<int>(list1.Count);
list2.AddRange(list1.Select(x => x.ID));
```

Comment: Yes you assume correctly, I just put GetIds there because I know some command should have been put there to extract Ids, I was thinking about Select but wasn't sure how to use it. thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Select` method. For example:

```
List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
var allIds = list1.Select(n => n.ID);
list2.AddRange(allIds);
```

You dont have to user `AddRange` method if your list is empty. You should just assign result of `Select` method to your destination list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   list2.AddRange(list1.Select(C => C.ID).ToList());
```